# Getting Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. when using useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-admin` framework. I wrote my custom component that displays images in a materialUI `GridList`. I had to implement `useState` function to determine what elements to display if user hovers over specific `Button`. However after implementing `useState` the app crashes with following error:

```
Error: Rendered fewer hooks than expected. This may be caused by an accidental early return statement.
```

My code:

```
const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false);

const onButtonHover = () =>
{
    setMouseOver(true);
}

const onButtonClose = () =>
{
    setMouseOver(false);
}

return <GridListTile key={id} onMouseLeave={onButtonClose} {...tileProps}>
        <img src={ImageService.getUrl(image)} className={classes.pngbgr} alt={title} />
        {mouseOver ?
            <div className={classes.tagsContainer}>
                <TagsShow source="tags" record={record} />
            </div>
        :
            null
        }
        <GridListTileBar
            className={classes.tileBar}
            title={title}
            subtitle={tags !== undefined && tags.length > 0 ?
                <Button className={classes.tagsButton} onMouseOver={onButtonHover} label="hf.action.showTags"><LabelIcon /></Button>
                :
                null
            }
        />
    </GridListTile>;
```

Then I am rendering my component in my Gallery model:

```
const GalleryList = props => (
    <List filters={<GalleryFilter />} pagination={<ListPagination />} perPage={30} sort={{ field: '_id', order: 'ASC' }} actions={<Actions />} {...props}>
        <GridList rowClick="show" getTileProps={getGalleryTileProps} />
    </List>
);
```

Any ideas why am I getting this error?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how are you using this custom component? Is it being called as a function - for eg, `CustomComponent()` somewhere outside?

Comment: @iamaatoh it is being called as a React Component <MyComponent />

Answer (score 0):

[This article by Kent C Dodds](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/dont-call-a-react-function-component/) might be related.

Can't be sure that this is your answer, without more details about how you are using the custom component outside - but looks like a violation of the following rules of hooks (quoted from the article)

> you need to make sure that the hooks are always called the same number of times for a given component.

Paraphrasing the article, if you use a component as a function call, say something like this:

```
return arr.map(CustomComponent)
```

... since it's being called and not "rendered", the component's hooks are being interpreted in scope of the parent component - and it would it would translate to something like this...

```
const ParentComponent() {
  return arr.map((item) => {
     // no. of hooks in ParentComponent depends on number of items
     const [mouseOver, setMouseOver] = useState(false);
     .. rest of your component
   }
}
```

...which violates the above rules of hooks mentioned.

Replacing that with this:

```
arr.map((item) => <CustomComponent item={item}/>)
```

makes React interpret the hooks as part of the custom component scope, and it doesn't them throw this error.

Hope this helps!

---

**Update**

Adding the update here for posterity

The component in question did indeed have a function call like below:

```
{ids.map(id => GridTile({ id, record: data[id], basePath, classes, rowClick, getTileProps, resource }))}
```

Switching to rendering it fixed the issue:

```
{ids.map(id => <GridTile id={id} record={data[id] } basePath={basePath} classes={classes} rowClick={rowClick} getTileProps={getTileProps} resource={resource} /> )}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I dont really understand this solution..my useState is a boolean so I cant return it using .map().

Comment: My solution was based on the assumption that you might be using your component as a function. Since you already clarified in the comments that you aren't and are using `<MyComponent />` ...I'm not sure if this exact answer would help you, except maybe just directionally

Comment: If you could add more details about how you are using your component, maybe I could try and help further

Comment: Im not quite sure if thats somewhat relevant to the issue...I am using my component in a List component that is made by react-admin framework:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/List.html

If I remove useState from the code example the app doesnt crash, but I lose the functionality

Comment: The `Rendered fewer hooks than expected` usually happens when the number of hooks being rendered in a component is not constant. Since your problem only occurs when you added the `useState` hook in this component, my first instinct was it might be related to its usage in some kind of length dependent iteration outside - similar to the the case in the article that I linked.

Comment: you are doing something like ```<List><My Component /></List> ``` ... then? using a custom iterator?

Comment: I updated my question with the code how I render my component in List

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216197/discussion-between-iamaatoh-and-adamsulc).