# is there a way to memoize a function that returns a random color in every iteration in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, memoization

I am building a react native contact app that generates a random color for every contact number. I want to memoize the returned value of the random color generator function on every iteration so when I am searching the contacts, the color won't be changing on every action.

currently, I am using react's useMemo to memoize the function result, but I am getting an invalid hook because I can not use hooks inside a normal function with a loop.

As my code below the useMemo hook is called only on the first render or when the component re-renders. I am only able to return one value because I can't use useMemo inside the map.

here is my code ⬇. Thanks for helping

```
const Contacts = () => {
  const [contact, setContact] = useState({});

  const randomColor = useMemo(() => randomColorGenerator(), []);


  useEffect(() => {}, []);

  const renderContacts = item => {
      return item.phoneNumbers.map(element => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={1}
          key={element.digits.toString()}
          }}
        >
          <View>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.firstName}</Text>
                  <Text>{element.digits}</Text>
                </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ));
  };

  const renderList = () => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        keyboardShouldPersistTaps="handled"
        data={contact}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return <View>{renderContacts(item)}</View>;
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={Styles.textStyle}>All Contacts</Text>
      {renderList()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: what do you want to do? have a memoized random color for each individual contact?

Comment: Exactly, I want each contact to have their own memoized color.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function - a React functional component. Then you'll be able to use `React.useMemo` inside it. Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62430666/getting-error-rendered-fewer-hooks-than-expected-when-using-usestate/62432592#62432592) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62463827/3545099) might help clarify better

```
// define it as a functional component
const RenderContacts = ({ item }) => {
     // useMemo inside that
     const randomColor = useMemo(() => randomColorGenerator(), []);

     // TODO: use randomColor somewhere

     return item.phoneNumbers.map(element => (
        <TouchableOpacity ...>
          ...
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ));
     )
}

const Contacts = () => {
  ...

  // extract this out into its own component
  // const renderContacts = item => {
  //    return item.phoneNumbers.map(element => (
  //      <TouchableOpacity
  //        activeOpacity={1}
  //        key={element.digits.toString()}
  //        }}
  //      >
  //        <View>
  //              <View>
  //                <Text>{item.firstName}</Text>
  //                <Text>{element.digits}</Text>
  //              </View>
  //        </View>
  //      </TouchableOpacity>
  //    ));
  // };


  const renderList = () => {
    return (
      <FlatList
        ...
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          // return <View>{renderContacts(item)}</View>;
          // render the component, don't call it as a function
          return <View><RenderContacts item={item} /></View>;
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text style={Styles.textStyle}>All Contacts</Text>
      {renderList()}
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this work for generating a memorized random color for each contact but I think when you add search functionality that updates the component state the colors are re-rendering while typing and searching for specific contacts. 
``` 
const updateContactState = text => setContact(text); -  additional method I have inside the component for the search function.
return ( 
    <View>
      <SearchBar updateContactState={updateContactState} /> -> search bar component
      <Text style={Styles.textStyle}>All Contacts</Text>
      {renderList()}
    </View>
  );
```

Comment: How does your search functionality work? Does it reset the items? You could wrap the individual contact with `React.memo` to memoize it, so that it doesnt mount/unmount, if the props don't change. However, if you list itself is getting recreated, then this might now work.

Comment: This is my serach function.
const searchContacts = value => {
    const filteredContact = inMemoryContact.filter(contactToFilter => {
      const contactLowerCase = `${contactToFilter.firstName} ${contactToFilter.lastName}`.toLowerCase();
      const searchTerm = value.toLowerCase();
      return contactLowerCase.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;
    });
    updateContactState(filteredContact);
  };

Comment: i tried to recreate your scenario [here](https://snack.expo.io/YCuWxNV_z) - to understand better; if it's a close enough replication, the data to your flatlist is changing. When you search for something, the other contacts aren't included in the array - so there's no way to prevent them from un-mounting. in my example, the random number is persistent **only** as long as its included in the search and hence, present in the array. when i enter a search term where it's excluded, it unmounts and is destroyed. the next time all items are displayed, it remounts again and gets a new random number

Comment: in this case, i'd suggest what @azundo's recommended - you should find a way to cache the colors within the color generator - the random color should be seeded with the contact id

Answer (score 0):

I would just suggest creating your own pure-javascript wrapper around `randomColorGenerator` that caches values based on a key to give a consistent result. Something like:

```
const memoizedRandomColorGenerator = function() {
  const cache = {};
  return function(k) {
    if (typeof cache[k] !== 'undefined') {
      return cache[k];
    }
    cache[k] = randomColorGenerator();
    return cache[k];
  }
}() // note that we are immediately invoking this function to close over the cache
```

Define that somewhere outside of your component so it is only created once.
Then use it in component

```
  const renderContacts = item => {
      return item.phoneNumbers.map(element => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          activeOpacity={1}
          key={element.digits.toString()}
          }}
        >
          <View style={{
            backgroundColor: memoizedRandomColorGenerator(element.digits.toString())
          }}>
                <View>
                  <Text>{item.firstName}</Text>
                  <Text>{element.digits}</Text>
                </View>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ));
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Color can be either property of the contact, that can be set earlier and stored inside the contact.

Or color can be function of the `${contact.firstName} ${contact.lastName}`.
You can get hexadecimal hash from the string, then color from hash.

This way you get persistent assignment between contacts and colors.

`useMemo` is intended for heavy calculations, that returns the same result, not random.